# Overwrite properties in java library

Tags: java

I have a Lib-A that has a dependency on com.atlassian.oai:swagger-request-validator-core. This dependency has a properties file [messages.properties](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/src/master/swagger-request-validator-core/src/main/resources/swagger/validation/messages.properties).

I have an App-A that has a dependency on Lib-A. If I place the messages.properties file in App-A, I am able to overwrite the properties, but if I place it in Lib-A, it doesn't overwrite. How do I overwrite the properties from Lib-A?

There seems to be no way of changing the path as well: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/src/master/swagger-request-validator-core/src/main/java/com/atlassian/oai/validator/report/MessageResolver.java#lines-26

Comment: Try adding that path to the CLASSPATH and see if Swagger can find them in the JAR.

Comment: It is able to find, but I want to overwrite the properties, not use the default one provided by the library.

Comment: Can’t you add your own modified copy of that file?

Comment: I tried adding the same resource to my project but it is still taking the properties from the library.

Comment: Can you please clarify for me -  are you trying to overwrite some/each of the properties in this file with your own values?

Comment: Yes, trying to overwrite some properties so that I can provide my own custom message.

Comment: I might pursue providing your own `MessageResolver` implementation, although it’s not clear where that would be injected with a cursory look.

Comment: If you want to individually set properties, you should try passing them as environment variables. I know this works well with spring boot from my experience, hope it will work for your application as well.
Example usage - 
To change the value of 
"validation.request.path.missing"
Pass an env variable named VALIDATION_REQUEST_PATH_MISSING

Comment: I am able to overwrite the properties if it is a direct dependency, but it doesn't work for transitive dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Easy peasy:

1. demo/**pom.xml**:

   ```xml
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>com.example</groupId>
     <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>  
     <dependencies>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
         <version>1.7.32</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>com.atlassian.oai</groupId>
         <artifactId>swagger-request-validator-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.22.0</version>
       </dependency>
     </dependencies>
   </project>
   ```
2. demo/**src/main/resources/swagger/validation/messages.properties** (case sensitive):

   ```properties
   validation.request.path.missing=FOO '%s'. # an existing key from ...
   # ...swagger-validator with custom message (and complying parameters)
   ```
3. demo/**src/main/java/com/example/demo/Main.java**:

   ```java
   package com.example.demo;

   import com.atlassian.oai.validator.report.MessageResolver;
   import com.atlassian.oai.validator.report.ValidationReport.Message;
   import org.slf4j.Logger;
   import static org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger;

   public class Main {

     private static final Logger log = getLogger(Main.class);
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       MessageResolver mr = new MessageResolver();
       Message m = mr.get("validation.request.path.missing", "bar");
       log.info("got message: {}", m == null ? null : m.getMessage());
     }
   }
   ```
4. (with these 3 files only, Execute) In your terminal (or in an IDE):

   ```bash
   >cd demo
   >mvn clean process-classes exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.demo.Main"
   ```
5. Output:

   ```bash
   [INFO] ...
   [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (default-cli) @ spring-data-demo ---
   [com.example.demo.Main.main()] INFO com.example.demo.Main - got message: FOO 'bar'.
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time:  4.775 s
   [INFO] Finished at: 2021-11-11T17:33:39+01:00
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```

---

If we delete/rename/move *our* messages.properties, we get (the original) `No API path found that matches request 'bar'`.

I.e. by only placing the file in the correct location (`classpath:/swagger/validation/messages.properties`), we could change the message(s) of a (default) `MessageResolver`.

---

Edit1:

I think this will "always work", since the files in your bin/target folder will have precedence over "resources in jars", but it depends on classpath/-loader/execution details. But under these conditions any (default) MessageResolver created in "your jvm", will prefer that/your `messages.properties`

---

If you do so, ensure **all** keys are available in **your** `messages.properties` (+ match parameter count(&semantics)), since when trying this:

```java
// message key not present in (our!) swagger/validation/messages.properties
log.info("got other message: {}", 
  mr.get("validation.request.operation.notAllowed", "foo", "bar")
);
```

,we get ;(;(:

```bash
[com.example.demo.Main.main()] INFO com.example.demo.Main - got other message: null
```

---

Edit2:

Instead of (effectively)overwriting/replacing the (default) "resource bundle", you can also have all of the "inheritance and fallback magic", by *addding* language, country, platform specific messages (but still falling back to the default ones.)

exemplary folder structure:

```
demo
--src
----main
------resources
--------swagger
----------validation
------------messages_en_GB.properties
------------messages_en_US.properties
------------messages_en.properties
------------messages_de.properties
------------...
```

See also:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-resourcebundle
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#default_behavior

---

Edit3:

I got it (replacing as "adding") also working on a transitive dependency, *but* i had to ensure, that :

- or `demo` is the only (direct) dependency.
- or it appears (locally in the pom) **before** `swagger-request-validator-core`.

That sounds not really reliable, but that's what i've found/tested.

And "beyond maven" (sorry used it), we can say: the dependency with customized messages, should appear in the *class path before* `swagger-request-validator-core.jar`

Comment: funny/interesting/promising, too: when you add translations for the messages (e.g. `messages_EN.properties`) + "locale to your runtime" ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

May you try this? (not tested) ->

```
public class CustomMessageResolver extends MessageResolver{
    private final ResourceBundle customMessages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MYPATH/custom_messages");

    public ValidationReport.Message get(@Nonnull final String key, final Object... args) {
        requireNonNull(key, "A message key is required.");
        final ValidationReport.Level level = levelResolver.getLevel(key);
        if (!customMessages.containsKey(key)) {
            log.warn("No message key found for '{}'", key);
            return null;
        }
        return new ImmutableMessage(key, level, format(customMessages.getString(key), args));
    }
}
```